# Java library for converting CSV file to SQL data table

Tags: java, sql

I am looking for a library I could import to my project that would take a csv file, then create and populate the datatable in SQL. Is there anything like that i could use straight out of the box?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly perform the inverse (dumping sql resultset to csv) with [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#sql-integration). It might be a good place to start.

```
java.sql.ResultSet myResultSet = ....
writer.writeAll(myResultSet, includeHeaders);
```

opencsv will at least do the tricky part of reading your csv file and handle all the encoding and character escaping nonsense.

Comment: Thanks, that is a start. Now, is there anythig that would write that into my SQL database?

Comment: this task of putting data into a table is so basic I don't think you'll find a library designed to do that.  You need 2 libraries: one to read CSV (which is suggested in this answer) and one to write to the database (that would be JDBC).